# Unable to update model from database after splitting entities into separate projects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have created a vanilla ASP.NET MVC 5 project with entity framework 6.1.3

I'm following this [article](http://nullablecode.com/2013/09/splitting-entity-framework-model-classes-separate-projects/) to the T. However, after splitting my entity classes into a separate project, I get this error message when I select the `Update model from database` in my `.edmx` file

[image: error message]

I have 3 projects in my sln.

1. Web
2. Entity
3. Data

I realized the exact point I start to get this error message is when I delete the old `.tt` file from my data project.

Comment: Have you done a "Search all" for "TimeManagementModel.Context" to see whether it's still lingering somewhere?

Comment: It doesn't exist anywhere